# How to give command-line arguments (sys.argv) when executing python session in Orgmode

Tags: org-mode, python, command-line-arguments, session

I want to run my python code (that'll eventually become standalone python script) in org-mode.
This script requires command line arguments (provided by `sys` lib's `sys.argv`).

How do I execute python code-block that contain `sys.argv` in org-mode? (and give appropriate arguments)

For example:

```
#+begin_src python :session mysess :results output
  # this part opens file
  print(sys.argv)
  fname = sys.argv[1]
  print(fname)
#+end_src
```

will cause:

```
>>> 
['']
org_babel_python_eoe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in __PYTHON_EL_eval
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/tmp/babel-vHlVQW/python-Ua2ZbY", line 3, in <module>
    fname = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently one could just use separate code blocks (like below) that won't `tangle`d into the actual output standalone file.

```
#+begin_src python :session mysess :results output :tangle no
  sys.argv= ['python', '/home/user/dir/to/file']
#+end_src
```

I didn't know `sys.argv` can directly changed with `sys.argv= ['python', '/home/user/dir/to/file']`